# Is there a net increase of temperature in thermal equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, equilibrium

If I have two objects sitting side by side let's say a water pump running at 10 degrees c and a processor running at 50 degrees c. The heat transfers from the hotter to the colder object until they reach equilibrium.

Is there an increase in temperature? Does the temperature of the pump and processor increase to 60 degrees c or does it move to 50 degrees c for both?

Answer (score 1):

For a body of mass $m_A$, specific heat capacity $c_A$ at initial temperature $T_A$, placed in contact with a body of mass $m_B$, specific heat capacity $c_B$ at initial temperature $T_B$, the equilibrium temperature, $T_{eq}$ reached will be given by $$T_{eq}=\frac{(m_Ac_AT_A+m_Bc_BT_B)}{(m_Ac_A+m_Bc_B)}.$$ This would give an equilibrium temperature somewhere in between $T_A$ and $T_B$. For example, if $c_A=c_B$ and $m_A=m_B$, then $T_{eq}=\frac12 (T_A + T_B)$. This assumes that $c_A$ and $c_B$ are constants independent of temperature – usually a fairly reasonable assumption. But it also assumes that energy conversions aren't taking place inside the bodies, which unfortunately means that it's not really appropriate for your 'powered' bodies, the pump and the processor. To make progress with these we'd need a more complicated analysis – unless we're allowed to turn them off before putting them in contact!

Now suppose that the bodies are not in contact, but separated by an air gap of about an inch (2.5 cm). Instead of heat being transferred by conduction between the bodies, there will be transfer by convection and radiation. The answer above still applies *in principle*, though it will take considerably longer for equilibrium to be reached. But we now have another serious complication. Transfers of heat to or from the *surroundings* (over given time) will now be comparable with, or greater than, transfers *between* the bodies themselves. There will then be no simple answer to your question, unless you accept the rather artificial addition of a thermally insulating wall surrounding both bodies (but not in the gap between them).

Comment: They aren't in direct contact, there is a spacing between them of about an inch. Yes you can turn them off if you want.

Comment: Please see extension to my answer, just added.

Comment: okay so in laymans terms Is there an increase in temperature? Does the temperature of the pump and processor increase to 60 degrees c or does it move to 50 degrees c for both?

Comment: @ Ninja2k. If you turn off the power supply to both, and place them near each other in the same insulated box they will reach a temperature somewhere between 10° and 50°. If you don't turn them off the temperatures of both will tend to equalise, but go on rising indefinitely, going above 50° and continuing to rise. I sense your frustration at not being given a straightforward answer to what you thought was a straightforward question. I'm afraid it wasn't as straightforward a question as it might have seemed. That's why the question was closed.